# How to proxy payload using reactive Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

I have a webservice endpoint that should just proxy the received payload from another internal endpoint.

My goal is to neither having to read input body I receive, nor the response the I want to return. I just want to proxy it.

The following works, but it's probably suboptimal converting the response to a `Mono<String>`. But how could I do better?

```
@RestController
public class ProxyController {
   @PostMapping("/proxy")
   public Mono<Object> proxy(InputStream payload) {
       return webClient.post().uri(url).bodyValue(payload).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: since we have no ida what data you are sending, what the endpoints look likem api description etc. how could we give any type of advice?

Comment: Well, if I don't want to read the input/output, but just hand it through, it does not matter which type of endpoints I connect to. My question is simply how I could best inject the input into my `@PostMapping`, and how I can then forward it via webclient. As well as return the response untouched. While the above works, I'm not sure if converting eg the response to a  `String.class` is best here, because that would deserialize the bytes into a string that I don't even read myself. So eg it might be better if I could somehow passthrough the bytes directly?

Comment: no you wrote "But how could I do better?" since we don't know all known parameters, then we can not give you any form of optimal answers.If you say "input" it could be anything, and different "input" has different "better" ways. We don't know if converting the answer to a string is better or not because we don't know what the input looks like. We know its json, but we have no idea, is it big, small, what is in the json, data, giant arrays, big, small etc. etc.

Comment: And also you need to define, what is "better"? What are you measuring, speed? whats the current speed? Memory footprint, then what is the current memory footprint? number of lines of code? less is "better"?

Comment: Well, so do I not know what kind of input I will receive. This should just be a simple passthrough proxy endpoint not touching the streams. And reading a stream to a string is probably worse than just handing the bytes through. But I don't know how.

Comment: Interesting, I landed in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to do using rest template

```
@RequestMapping("/pass-to-service/**")
fun passThroughPostRequest(request: HttpServletRequest, @RequestBody body: Any?): ResponseEntity<String> {
    val method = HttpMethod.resolve(request.method)!!
    val requestEntity = RequestEntity(body, method, URI.create(myServiceUrl))
    val responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String::class.java)

    // response entity might have crazy headers, so add some decent/needed and ship back
    val httpHeaders = HttpHeaders()
    httpHeaders.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

    return ResponseEntity(responseEntity.body, httpHeaders, responseEntity.statusCode)
}
```

In above example, I avoided as much of serialisation and deserialisation that I could. Kept it a passthrough from servlet.

Similarly, I am trying something like this using webclient:

```
@PostMapping("/v1/cars/{carId}/details")
    fun ingestCarInfo(
        @PathVariable("carId") carId: UUID,
        request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, @RequestBody body: Mono<CarDetailsReqDto>
    ) {
        /** Step 1: I wanted to do some activity here */

        /** Step 2: return a success response immediately, as my client do not care about the data processed.
         * What I am unsure here? Does this return immediately without getting to next step
         * */
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())

        /** Step 3: Fire & Forget request */
        val uri = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString("http://localhost:8080")
            .path("/v3/cars/{carId}/details")
            .build().encode().toUri()

        webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST).uri(uri)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(body))
            .header("OnewayRequest", "true")
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .block()

    }
```

Here, I haven't made everything generic, my body still has a shape defined but reactive. If it is a wildcard pass-through I would type it `Mono<Any?>`

NOTE: Still I am working on this. Will update once I find a better solution, also I need to check the performance and speed in realtime.